# Möbius strip and $\mathscr O(-1)$. Or $\mathscr O(1)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, vector-bundles

On the *real* $\textbf P^1$ we have these algebraic line bundles: $\mathscr O(1)$ and $\mathscr O(-1)$.

Which one corresponds to the Möbius strip? (Both are $1$-twists of $\textbf P^1\times\textbf A^1$, so how to distinguish them? Yes, by means of their transition functions, but how do they tell me which one has the Möbius strip as total space?) And what is the total space of the other one?

I can only imagine that non-orientability should correspond to the absence of global sections, so I would bet on $-1$, but with no real reason.

Also, I can't figure if to every $\mathscr O(d)$ there corresponds a different total space, or there are repetitions. Of course, by viewing those bundles as holomorphic bundles, there are only two surfaces up to diffeomorphism. But what about the algebraic category?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**
This is a corrected answer. Many thanks to Ben who pointed out the idiocy of my original  version.

Given an arbitrary field $k$, the Picard group of $\mathbb P^1_k$ (consisting of the isomorphism classes of   algebraic line bundles)  is isomorphic to  $\mathbb Z$ *via* the degree map  $$\text {deg} : \text {Pic} (\mathbb P^1_k) \stackrel {\cong }{\to}     \mathbb Z  ,$$  the inverse isomorphism being $$    \mathbb Z  \stackrel {\cong }{\to}   \text {Pic} (\mathbb P^1_k) :n\mapsto    \mathscr O(n)        $$
In the case $k=\mathbb R$ things become quite interesting because the real points $\mathbb P^1_\mathbb R (\mathbb R)$ of the projective line $\mathbb P^1_\mathbb R$ are endowed with the structure of a real differentiable manifold diffeomorphic to the circle $S^1$.
And that manifold  has a differentiable Picard group $\text {Pic}^{\text {diff}} (\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)) $ of order two generated by the Möbius bundle $M$, so that we have a group isomorphism $$  \text {Pic}^{\text {diff}} (\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R))  \stackrel {\cong }{\to} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z: M\mapsto \bar 1        $$
We then have a forgetful group homomorphism $\text {Pic} (\mathbb P^1_\mathbb  R)\to \text{Pic}^{\text {diff}} (\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R)) $ forgetting the algebraic structure of a line bundle and retaining only its differentiable structure.
In the above identification this morphism is just reduction modulo $2$: $$\text {Pic} (\mathbb P^1_\mathbb  R)\to \text{Pic}^{\text {diff}} (\mathbb P^1(\mathbb R))\cong \mathbb Z: \mathscr O(n) \mapsto M^n\cong \bar n$$
In particular *both*  $\mathscr O(1)$ and $\mathscr O(-1)$ are sent to the Möbius bundle, which answers your question (I hope!)

Comment: I know this answer is very old, but why is the smooth picard group of the real projective line, $\operatorname{Pic}^\mathrm{diff}(\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R}))$, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? I know that this amounts to compute $\operatorname{Pic}^\mathrm{diff}(S^1)$, but I still don't see why that is the case in this situation. Is there any reference where I can look this up?